# Checking Table Existance: Table doesn't exist while it exists

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

```
public bool CheckTblExist(string TblName)
    {
        try
        {  
            string cmTxt = "select case when exists" 
            + "((select * from information_schema.tables " 
            + "where table_name = '" + TblName + "')) then 1 else 0 end";

            var cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmTxt);
            if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1) exists = true;
            MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table Exists.");
        }
        catch
        {
            exists = false;
            MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table does not Exist.");
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

Using VS2012,C# I've created manually mdf file named Tasoo1.mdf inside App_Data with connection named con. Tasoo.mdf already has 1 table named '1010' created using

```
string cmdText = "CREATE TABLE [" + tblname + "]" 
                 + "(column_name1 int,column_name2 int,column_name3 int)";
```

Excauting the code, gave me- table doesn't exist? any idea how to solve this..thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Apart from answer below personally I'd use select count(*) from information_schema.tables where ... and drop the case altogether. I'm not sure what the above query really does but you shuldn't need a catch handler just because the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually ALL answers are correct, the most point I needed is to read the exception and yep It was again easy by that...really thanks alot for all of you guys specialy who detailed the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one statement under your if statement, i.e. `exists = true`. Your MessageBox.Show is outside the if statement. So even if the if statement returns false, you will always get the message that the table exists. Enclose it in `{}`.

```
if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1) 
{    
     exists = true;
     MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table Exists.");
}
```

Your current code:

```
if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1) exists = true;
MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table Exists."); // this is irrespective of the if
```

> Excauting the code, gave me- table doesn't exist?

You are showing that in your catch block. That means you are getting some exception. Its not a good idea to have an empty catch block. Catch the exception and see what is going wrong.

```
catch(SqlException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   //handle exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks Habib, I really appreciate your support but this didn't solve it. Still give me-  table does not Exist.

Comment: @AdnanAl-Husain, that is because you are getting an exception. Catch the exception and see what is wrong. Probably your sql statement is not correct

Comment: @Habib - Personally, I'm betting that the exception relates to the fact that the command is never associated with a connection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, wow, nice catch. That should be an answer.

Comment: hhh Damien what you said is correct, you won the bet. Silly mistake again. Thank you alot my brothers Habib and Damien. Habib if you are saudi maybe you'll be interested and assist me on this project!.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmTxt);
```

This command is never associated with a connection object of any kind (let alone an open one)

```
catch
    {
        exists = false;
        MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table does not Exist.");
    }
```

This code *ignores* whatever exception has occurred, and just reports that the table doesn't exist. If you'd actually specified a variable to contain the exception, and examined it, you'd have probably found out about the top issue I mentioned.

---

Even once you fix those, of course, your code (as written) shouldn't *throw* an exception anyway when a table doesn't exist. It will just have a different result value when you call `ExecuteScalar`.

With so many issues, this feels like a homework problem.

You can re-write the later part as:

```
if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
{
   MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table exists.");
   return true;
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show(TblName + " table does not exist.");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to try

```
bool tabex;
try
{ 
    var cmd = new OdbcCommand(
      "select case when exists((select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = '" + tableName + "')) then 1 else 0 end");

    tabex= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        tabex = true;
        var cmdOthers = new OdbcCommand("select 1 from " + tableName + " where 1 = 0");
        cmdOthers.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        tabex = false;
    }
}
```

Check this also : [Using C#, how do you check if a table exists in SQL?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservermigration/thread/a6d13bf2-f56f-40bd-9210-8a0ed4270a78/)

Answer (score 0):

When you say it gives table doesn't exist, I assume you mean the second message box is showing?  This is caused by an exception being thrown.  You really need to catch the exception object being thrown and it will tell you what your problem is.